# Swift_TransportException in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running Laravel 5.5 and when i try to send email i got  **Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""**.

I'm on localhost and i use Mailtrap to catch outgoing emails it was working perfect with the same settings but after a while i got that exception.

what weird is when i change my IP using a vpn it works and when i disable it it won't

i contact their support and asked if my IP is banned and they say no

So anyone can help me out i'm really confused 
Thank you in advance.

**PS (I've already read most of similar topics here but none of them has same problem)**

Comment: its likely a network issue.
or maybe your timeout is not set up...  Share your code

Comment: i don't think it's related to code because as i mentioned it works when i'm changing my ip address

Answer (score 1):

This has started happening after upgrading to 5.5 to anyone who was using localhost with Mailtrap, Mailhog, etc. It worked for me once I got explicit with the local IP and switched to smtp:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

#### Edit:

I assumed you were using a localhost mail service, since you are actually using Mailtrap externally I'm not sure anymore, but I was receiving the exact same error on localhost until switching the IP and transfer protocol.

Comment: i was using mailtrap from the beginning i did not use any localhost mail service, and how can i send emails if i use my local IP on "MAIL_HOST" ?

Comment: @AdamKeen It is for development with something like [Mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog), [Mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.5 using SwiftMailer 6.0 and this is the reason why mail transport isn't working.
Swift_Transport_MailTransport(which you are trying to use) was removed from Swift Mailer 6.0 that's why you need to use SMTP transport instead.

Comment: Ok, So what's the solution to bypass it ?

Comment: use smtp transport instead

Comment: I did and it works, but only in remote, not in localhost... do you Know why ?

Comment: I think that smpt have not been setup correctly. Try to follow some tutorial. In my case it perfectly works with mailcatcher